# CSS: Responsive rectangle: Div got cut when resized

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize

I am trying to make a responsive rectangle that is centered in the middle of the page with some contents inside.

However, when I am re-sizing it, the div `#result` got cut out, provided that I have the `min-height: 350px;` and `max-height: 650px;` declared.
Ideally, I would like to `min-height: 350px;` and as the page is being resized, the `max-height: 650px;`. I have also tried `height: 30%;` but it doesn't give me any luck...

So it would be very nice if someone could tell me the reason why the div got cut out please :)))

This is how it looks before resizing:
[image]
Resized (please note the head of the figure):
[image]
When it is in media screen mode (everything works fine!):
[image]

And the code is here:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
a, img, input{ outline: none; border:none; color: #000; }

/*
*, *:before, *:after {
     box-sizing: border-box; }
*/

.input-underline-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
}

.underline {
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

#formWrapper{
 float: right;
 margin-top: 30px;
 width: 360px;
 } 


#formWrapper{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 600px;
}

#form{
 margin-inline-start: 15%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
 min-width: 400px;
 max-width: 600px;
/*  height: 30%; */
 min-height: 350px;
 max-height: 600px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: white;
}

#form:before{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 0;
}

#formContent{
 padding: 2%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 96%;
 height: 96%;
}

#fillInForm{
 float: left;
 width: inherit;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.user{
 float: left;
 padding: 0 0.4em 0 0.4em}

#OK{
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 background: none;
}


#result{
 width: inherit;
 height: 120px;
}

#resultText{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 100px; 
 width: 50%;
 min-width: 200px;
 max-width: 300px;
 
}

#resultFigure{
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 margin-top: 30px;
 min-width: 200px;
 max-width: 300px;
}

#userFigure{

 margin-right: 50%;
 position: inherit;

}

#button{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 5%;
 left: 37%;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 background: none;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 628px) {
    
 .underline {
     background-color: black;
     z-index: 0;
     height: 1px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     width: 100%;
 }
    
 #form{
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 500px;
  } 
  #form #formContent #result{
   width: inherit;
   height: 120px;
   } 
   #form #formContent #result #resultText{
   float: left;
   margin-top: 100px; 
   width: 50%;
   max-width: 150px;
   }
 
   #form #formContent #result #resultFigure{
   margin-top: -100px;
   float: right;
   width: 50%;
   max-width: 150px;
   }
  
}
```

```html
   <div id = "formWrapper">   
    <div id = "form">
     <div id = "formContent">
      <a> Hello</a>   
      <div id = "fillInForm">
       <div class = "user">
        <img src = "http://placebear.com/30/100" />
        <br>
        <span class="input-underline-wrapper">
         <input type = "text" placeholder = "enter a name" id = "homme" />
         <div class="underline"> </div>     
        </span>
         <button type ="button" id = "OK">OK</button>
       </div>
       <div class = "user">      
        <img src = "http://placebear.com/30/100" />
        <br>
        <span class="input-underline-wrapper"> 
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "enter a name" id = "femme" />
        <div class="underline"> </div>      
       </span>
       <button type ="button" id = "OK">OK</button>

       </div>
       <div class = "user">       
        <img src = "http://placebear.com/30/100" />
        <br>
        <span class="input-underline-wrapper"> 
         <input type = "text" placeholder = "enter a name" id = "enfant" />
         <div class="underline"> </div>     
       </span>
       <button type ="button" id = "OK">OK</button>

       </div>
      </div>
      <div id = "result">
       <div id = "resultText">
        <div id = "takeALookInsideWith">
         <a> Go To: </a>
        </div>
        <div id = "userName">
         userName Test
        </div> 
       </div>
       <div id = "resultFigure">
        <div id = "userFigure">
         <img src = "http://placebear.com/30/100" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <button type ="button" id = "button">ENTER</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Use [Bootstrap grid examples](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is pretty simple :)

your element: #formContent is positioned absolute. When you have a element positioned absolute inside an element that is positioned relative your parent will not have the absolute element in it's "flow". So it wont scale if the absolute element gets bigger.

if you change

```
#formContent {
    position: absolute;
}
```

To:

```
#formContent {
    position: relative;
}
```

You'll see that the parent starts scaling with your #formContent element.

I Hope this helped you out a bit. I suggest you take a quick look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for a more covering explanation.

Good Luck!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem could you validate it as answered? :)

Comment: Hello, it solved my problem but then now it raised to another problem... :P The `ENTER` button is no longer sticking at the bottom now.. I have tried to fix it by declaring a `px` or `%`. It does not stick to the bottom after I start resizing it... Is it possible if you could address why please? Cheers x

Comment: you can "float: left" (or "overflow:hidden") your #formContent to make it size after content inside of it. So it will expand to the bottom. And because the button is postioned absolute to its relative parent. It sticks to the bottom again :)